# Wordpress Contact Form Error. Site is down

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

**Error:**
My Wordpress website is down i don't know why i'm getting this error.
i've deactivate contact form7 already but still facing this issue.
if anyone know how to resolve this please help.

```
{"mailSent":false,"into":"#wpcf7-f6160-o1","captcha":null,"message":"One or more fields have an error. Please check and try again.","invalids":[{"into":"span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap.Company","message":"The field is required.","idref":null}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for this . just logged in to Cpanel and clean my super cache of Googlepage speed, then it started working. hope this will help others also 
:)

Answer (score 0):

1. Rename the plugins folder to something else
2. Login to website, go to plugins page
3. Being on plugins page, rename plugins folder back to "plugins" and reload.
4. All the plugins will come deactivated. Now except contact form activate other plugins

Comment: My other pages are working except frontpage and contact-page.

Comment: these page have the contact form, follow the process to disable/deactivate it first. Then you can troubleshoot the problem with a local installation.

Comment: My contact form in the footer which is working on all pages. plus I've followed disabling and deactivate plugin after that still I have the same issue.